# OpenCV2 Write to webcam python

Tags: python, pip, opencv

Can I do something like this?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
wri = cv2.device(0)

while 1:
   ret, val = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read(), cv2.RGB2GRAY)
   if ret:
      wri.setCurrentFrame(val)
   if cv2.WaitKey(0) == 27:
       break
cap.release()
wri.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to make something like ManyCam.

I have researched and have not been able to find anything like this.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: To make my webcam grayscale but stream the grayscale stream to apps like zoom

Comment: you're gonna need a "virtual webcam". there are examples for that. that functionality is *not* part of OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the VideoCapture object is strictly responsible for capturing(read) an image from the stream(webcam, video file, RTSP, e.t.c.).
Then you can do any further processing with any of the opencv functions

Now, the webcam hardware is a device you read from, not write to.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question.

Comment: You know, now that I think about it, I am trying to make a virtual camera in python - Not write to an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Try of this way

```
import cv2
  
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  
while(True):
      
    ret, frame = capture.read()
 
    grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    cv2.imshow('video gray', grayFrame)
    cv2.imshow('video original', frame)
      
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
  
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That's it

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do that, I am wondering if I can make my real webcam actually display the gray stream for any app that uses a webcam